# Does spring-boot-starter-webflux include spring-boot-starter-web?

Tags: spring-webflux

Can I use the existing `spring-boot-starter-web` coding scheme with only `spring-boot-starter-webflux` added?? without `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spring-boot-starter-webflux` provides the relevant dependencies for a Spring WebFlux application, from Jackson to the `spring-webflux` module for annotation and functional programming models.

`spring-boot-starter-web` does the same for Spring MVC.

Having both on the classpath means that you want a Spring MVC app and still use the new `WebClient` provided by Spring WebFlux in that application.

As mentioned in [the Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux), you should add `spring-boot-starter-webflux` if you want to create a Spring WebFlux app and avoid adding `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: When one find the documentation for RestTemplate, it tells you to instead use WebClient. WebClient is provided by spring-boot-starter-webflux. This implies that your app will have to be a webflux app if you're going to use WebClient? Or would you then include both dependencies (MVC takes presedence) but you use WebClient anyways?